# Sqlite3 won't fetch database rows although they exist

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

My problem got me so confused that I've decided to finally create an account and ask for help :

I created a database called gamesapp.db with a table called gamess. When I check it in db browser, I can see two rows that I created earlier.

In my program, I connect to the gamesapp database, execute select * from gamess and fetchall to print it on HTML, but the fetchall returns blank list.

Here is the code :

```
con = sql.connect('gamesapp.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from gamess")

print cur.fetchall()
```

I've also tried doing

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print row
```

with no luck. The fetchall() only seems to work when I create the table within the program with

```
cur.execute(create table...)
```

It seems weird to me, because if I change the "gamess" to something different, Python says that there is no such table, also if I change the database name it says it doesn't exist - I just can't get where the problem is.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is the same exact `.db` file used in both cases?

Comment: use full path to `gamesapp.db` in `connect()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The fetchall() only seems to work when I create the table within the program with* `cur.execute(create table...)`

This is because you're not opening the database file you think you are.

`sql.connect('gamesapp.db')` is relative to the directory where the program was started. If your code is executed on a web server who knows where that might be? But you can be assured it isn't the same as when you test the code on the command line. (You can check with `import os; os.getcwd()`)

To be sure use a full path to the database file, and make sure the user the web server is running as has permission to read and write to it.

```
con = sql.connect('/full/path/to/my/gamesapp.db')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was unable to find information about it and I'm not yet into it deep enough to have thought about it myself. Works perfectly now.